# Refresh after second browser close

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser

I have 1 browser, when click one of the button. It will trigger another browser.
The code as below.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'InventoryReceive.aspx?', null, 'height=110,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);
```

On the second browser, it will allow user to do some update and will close after that. the close code as below.

```
  Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> { self.close() }</script>");
```

Does any idea how can I refresh the first browser when the second browser has been close???

Your comment and suggestion is much appreciated!!!!!!

I am using asp.net C#

Comment: @nadeem it's quite useful, but I couldn't close the second browser and the parent keep calling the child even I didnt click the button to trigger it.. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @nadeem is it because I call the new page from a btn_click event, and 
        window.opener.location.reload(); is reload the opener.location so will keep reload the btn_click whever I close it?